# images with transparency return to black when bunched

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor, 3d-view, transparency

Each plane with grass has transparency on it so that if I just rendered one grass plane it would not be a problem but when i duplicate them then they return to black[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Render* tab > *Light Paths* > *Max Bounces*, you may need to increase the *Transparency* value.

[image]